# Settings as a modal for a gnome shell extension

Tags: javascript, gnome-3, gnome-shell-extensions

I'm working a Gnome Shell Extension and this one will require some settings (a path to a folder, an url and checkbox (switch on/off)).

I was wondering if it was possible to make it only using javascript for Gnome 3, or something like Python was required.

The only example I found was this extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/135/web-application-menu/, and it uses Python.

If it's possible to use javascript, do you have any link pointing to doc on how to do it ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find any documentation about it (at the time, the documentation about gnome-shell is pitfully absent), but it seems the code located in `gnome-shell/js/ui/modalDialog.js` can be very helpful.

In Fedora, it's located in

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/uimodalDialog.js
```

I'll update it if I have something that is working.